# How to "create a Instagram Account using a Business Account"?

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api

I was trying to log in into my app with Facebook Log In For Business for testing purpose. And it shows me the following message:

"You don't have any Instagram Accounts. To continue, you'll need to create a Instagram Account using a Business Account and come back here."

The Facebook account I am using has already created a correlated Instagram Business Account and a correlated Facebook Business Account, so I have no idea what it is talking about. When I tried to use my Facebook Account to create an Instagram Account, it just log me into the existing Instagram Account that has been connected to my Facebook Account.

What does it mean by "create a Instagram Account using a Business Account" and how should I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out what it means is to connect the page to the Instagram account.

So what I did to get through this: (unsure which one is the one let me pass)

Have a business account on Facebook and on Instagram.

Connect the Facebook business page to the Instagram account. (This creates some certain relationship between the business account and the Instagram account)

During the login process, make sure to pick the Facebook business account that is related to that connected page.

Then you shall see Facebook is able to see the Instagram Account.